# How to load more than 50 youtube videos on UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, uitableview, youtube-api

I am using AFNetworking to parse JSON data on UITableView. YouTube api give JSON data for max 50 videos. I need to load more than 100 videos and i am not sure how to do that.

Here is the url i am using to get the files from the API:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50

And here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *urlAsString = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50";


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // This will initiate the request and parse the data using apples JSONSerialization

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {



        self.videoMetaData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];

        // This will have all the sq and hq thumbnails

        self.allThumbnails = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the `start-index`-option. For example:

1. Get 50 results with this URL:
   `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50`
2. Get the next 50 results by adding `&start-index=51`:
   `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=51`

See the [YouTube API v. 2.0 reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#start-indexsp).

Comment: ok so i have to use multiple url. How do i view all the result on one page ?

Comment: You could put the results in an `NSMutableArray` for example.

Comment: so should i use AFJSONRequestOperation multiple times and then add the result to a new array ?

Comment: Precisely how you do it us up to you, but yes, that is a solution.